# NetBeans ha dejado de ejecutar Servlets

Tags: java, netbeans, servlets

soy un novato en esto de la programación y mientras estaba haciendo unos ejercicios relacionados con JSP y Bases de Datos me ha sucedido el siguiente problema:

Soy usuario de NetBeans 12.3, y tengo proyectos creados tanto en esa misma versión como en anteriores, y todos ellos se me ejecutaban con normalidad. Esto era así hasta ayer, que de golpe comenzaban a aparecer de forma intercalada "Error 404" y "Error 500" en dos de mis proyectos, sin haber hecho cambio en el código. Para asegurarme de que no era algo que hubiese podido tocar yo, probé a crear Servlets con su contenido por defecto en Proyectos Web de prueba, y ni siquiera me ejecuta dichos Servlet.

Es como si el propio IDE hubiera perdido la capacidad de crear/ejecutar los Servlets.

Comparto el código del Servlet por defecto:

```
public class servlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try ( PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet servlet</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet servlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
```

}

Y del Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="4.0" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.servlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano!